# How to set text direction on Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

How can I set text direction (rotate) on Canvas. Vertical for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simpest way is:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.rotate(90, x, y);
    canvas.drawText("text", x, y, textPaint);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`rotate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float,%20float,%20float%29) method to specify the rotation of the elements that are going to be painted next.

Additional note: Be sure to read the rest of the [`Canvas` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) as well, as it has lots of methods to manipulate it (assuming you need more than rotating texts at some stage)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple vertical text implementation and rotation.

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView{
final boolean topDown;

 public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
  super(context, attrs);
  final int gravity = getGravity();
  if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
     setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
     topDown = false;
  }else
     topDown = true;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
  super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
  setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  TextPaint textPaint = getPaint(); 
  textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
  textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

  canvas.save();

  if(topDown){
     canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
     canvas.rotate(90);
  }else {
     canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
     canvas.rotate(-90);
  }


  canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

  getLayout().draw(canvas);
  canvas.restore();
}
}
```

By default, rotated text is from top to bottom. If you set

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

then it's drawn from bottom to top.

Comment: For me it's very complicated example, and I have seen it before here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262494/draw-text-vertically-on-canvas. I don't understand, while it does't work in my code, but it is not important now. I've added my solution, it works and very simple. Thanks!