# How to drawText vertically on custom View in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to drawText vertically at custom `View`?
If I write text like `canvas.drawText("TEST", 0, 0, paint);`. The text will be printed horizontally on the canvas. How can I rotate it to vertical?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262494/draw-text-vertically-on-canvas. check this might help

Comment: Yeah thanks, I implemented in this way.canvas.save();
               canvas.rotate(-90, x, y);
               canvas.drawText(date, x,y, paint);
               canvas.restore();

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but, it is unanswered so I have written.

You can use **path** to draw text on one path

```
private val path = Path()
path.moveTo(rect.centerX().toFloat(), height.toFloat())
path.lineTo(rect.centerX().toFloat(), 0F)
canvas.drawTextOnPath("Lalit jadav Lalit jadav Lalit jadav", path, 0F, 0F, textPaint)
```