# Android rotate TextView in API Level >= 8

Tags: android, rotation, textview

I have simple TextView

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:rotation="45"
   android:text="Simple text" />
```

The text wont be rotated to 45 degree on Android 2.2.2.

I saw different threads, but everybody is doing an animation. I don't want to animate. All I want is to rotate the textview.

Comment: subclass textview and override onDraw. It is really simple

Comment: In addition to 'blackbelt' response you can check example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262494/draw-text-vertically-on-canvas

Comment: follow this tutorial http://eleanordarephdjournal.blogspot.in/2011/03/another-good-android-example-with.html

Answer (score 18):

In android for any new view there is a method called [setRotation(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29) you can use it

```
textview.setRotation(float);
```

but please note that this method is Added in API level 11

so if you want to support it you can use this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {

    RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(oldAngel, newAngel);
    animation.setDuration(100);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    textview.startAnimation(animation);
} else {

    textview.setRotation(progress);
}
```

Comment: setRotation() in java equals to rotation in xml, and they are both rotate the whole TextView, but not the text in the TextView.

Answer (score 3):

I found "android:rotation" is not work in SDK 21,in other words is Android 5.0.  But i just found this problem in layout preview, not test in really device.